# NSTextMovement values

Tags: objective-c, notifications

A 'notification' message contains values called NSTextMovement, is there a list somewhere that tells what the different values are?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try [searching the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=nstextmovement)?

Comment: Yes I did, could not find anything, probably do not know what to search for other than 'NSTextMovement'.

Comment: That's exactly the search that I've linked. One of the five results is `NSText`, which has what you're seeking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Movement Codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000367-SW1)

```
enum {
   NSIllegalTextMovement = 0,
   NSReturnTextMovement  = 0x10,
   NSTabTextMovement     = 0x11,
   NSBacktabTextMovement = 0x12,
   NSLeftTextMovement    = 0x13,
   NSRightTextMovement   = 0x14,
   NSUpTextMovement      = 0x15,
   NSDownTextMovement    = 0x16,
   NSCancelTextMovement  = 0x17,
  NSOtherTextMovement    = 0
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume the 0x10 notation is base 16. Interesting side note: I am using it in the textDidEndEditing notation method and it tells me what object I was in (textfield, etc) and whether I pressed the 'Return' or 'Tab' key or just clicked in another field.

Answer (score 0):

Since MacOS 10.13, the movement codes have been collected in an enum: [NSTextMovement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextmovement).

At least in Swift, it gives you better pattern matching and much shorter names – `.tab` instead of `NSTextMovementTab` etc.